# Can anyone recommend a good HTML5 jQuery file uploader plugin or working code?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, plugins, upload

I'm not interested in the drag and drop, neither the multiple file upload.  Just simply the fact you can upload a file via AJAX.  I have a heavy weight template that I do not want to mess with as it is very nice as it is.  I have tried the whole iframe thing and to add all the styles in the related page is such a pain, especially when trying to get the right design back on track.

[image: Here's what it looks like]

The 'delete avatar' works perfectly as that's just a simple post form through AJAX/jQuery but when a user selects the file, I want it so it automatically uploads the file (not bothered about a loader, just an spinner would do in the avatar preview) via the change event.

Everything is set up through very easy jQuery events so I want to completely customise the plugin, without any styles (which I find a lot of plugins already have built in).  I have been thinking about writing it myself without any plugin but feel this will just save some time.  And the fact I wouldn't know where to start also doesn't help!

If anyone has done this before, any help or links would be great to try and get towards an image that can be uploaded without the page refreshing, the use of Flash or iframes.

**I do not particularly want to use a plugin, it would be great to know if there is a way to completing this without refreshing the page, by uploading a file. It seems the best way to go about it in this situation is to use an iframe. This way, the image is uploaded without the page refreshing and the `iframe` is more supported than using an HTML5 solution.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uploadifive uses the HTML5 file API to avoid the tricks with flash and frames you mentioned: http://www.uploadify.com/download/download-uploadifive-standard/

Answer (score 4):

http://www.plupload.com/ - Plupload - You can customize it to only do HTML5 and some nice customizations.